# Turn down volume of WasapiLoopbackCapture C#

Tags: c#, volume, naudio, wasapi

This is a small part of my code:

```
private void Connect(IPEndPoint endPoint, INetworkChatCodec codec)
    {
        waveIn = new WasapiLoopbackCapture();

        //waveIn.WaveFormat = codec.RecordFormat;
        waveIn.DataAvailable += waveIn_DataAvailable;
        waveIn.RecordingStopped += waveIn_RecordingStopped;

        waveIn.StartRecording();

        udpSender = new UdpClient();
        udpSender.Connect(endPoint);

        connected = true;
    }
```

I need to turn down the volume of the sound that the **WasapiLoopbackCapture** records. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

WASAPI captures samples as floating point numbers (4 bytes IEEE float). So you could multiply each one by 0.5f if you wanted to reduce the volume.